# Embedly not creating thumbnails for Facebook pages?

Tags: telescope, embedly

I've been building an application using Telescope that creates a grid of Embedly cards for URLs from different types of pages - Facebook, Soundcloud, Youtube, or any other webpage.

Everything worked all right until yesterday, when I found that Embedly is not able to generate thumbnails for URLs that link to Facebook pages in particular (and I mean public pages, not even profiles). It's only able to resolve 'Title', and keeps the 'Body' and 'Thumbnail URL' empty. All other links work properly as before.

Has something changed with Embedly? What should I do to make Facebook page based cards now?

Comment: Can you use the same facebook link and check if the card gets generated successfully on embedly site? - http://embed.ly/code

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. In fact, none of the pages on Facebook create thumbnails on the Embedly site.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, if you try creating a card from a page on Facebook, it won't work. But you can create cards by putting a link to a photo (profile, cover, or any other).